# How to create bit ranges with terms defined as logic

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I understand the following code will not compile, but is there something similar that compiles?

```
logic [7:0] complete_set, partial_set;  
logic [2:0] msb_bit, lsb_bit;  

always_comb complete_set = <driven by a logic equation>;  
always_comb msb_bit = <driven by a logic equation>;  
always_comb lsb_bit = <driven by a logic equation>;  

always_comb partial_set[msb_bit:lsb_bit] = complete_set[msb_bit:lsb_bit];
```

Comment: What you are asking for is not combinational logic until you specify what the values of the bits outside the msb /lsb range should be.

Comment: There is no vcs syntax to do it in one operation, you would need a loop, and assign it bit by bit. And it is a latch, not a comb, because you are potentially not assigning all the bits in the same simulation cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some bitwise decisions like this. I just assumed you would want to set the other bits to zero, but you could also set it to don't cares (1'bx).

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
    partial_set[i] = (i < lsb_bit) || (i > msb_bit) ? 1'b0 : complete_set[i];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the unspecified bits to be 0, you can do this in one line:

```
   always_comb partial_set = complete_set & (2**(msb_bit+1-lsb_bit)-1)<<lsb_bit;
```

But I think a `for` loop would be much easer for someone else to understand

```
always_comb begin
       partial_set = '0; // or whatever the unspecified bits should be
       for(int ii = lsb_bit; ii <= msb_bit; ii++)
           partial_set[ii] = complete_set[ii]
    end
```